# AWS EBS - How to find last volume modification time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

can't increase volume size due to

> Wait at least 6 hours between modifications per EBS volume.

Is there a way to get the last volume modification time so I know when I can modify the volume again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [describe-volumes-modifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes-modifications.html):

> Describes the most recent volume modification request for the specified EBS volumes.

The output includes `start-time`.